# Call private method from the world in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, encapsulation

I realy don't understand why it works, but below code shows an example of calling private method from the world without any friend classes:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void someMethod(){
        std::cout << "A::someMethod";
    }
};
class B : public A
{
private:
    virtual void someMethod(){
        std::cout << "B::someMethod";
    }
};
int main(){
    A* a = new B;
    a->someMethod();
}
```

outputs:

```
B::someMethod
```

Doesn't it violates encapsulation rules in C++? For me this is insane. The inheritance is public, but the access modifier in derived class is changed to private, thus the `someMethod()` in class B is private. So in fact, doing `a->someMethod()`, we are directly calling a private method from the world.

Comment: You're using a pointer to an 'A' object in which the method is public. It doesn't violate anything

Comment: It's stupid and broken, but it's how C++ works.

Comment: The use case is so rare that I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: This is neither stupid or broken, because that's the way *polymorphism* works: The user of `a` might not know what type `a` is pointing to (the dynamic type of `*a`). The user of `a` might only know the "interface" `class A`, and uses the functions this interface provides. The function of this interface is `public`, therefore it's allowed. That you can override the function in a derived class with a different access modifier allows more flexible designs.

Comment: @DyP: The `private` access modifier is a lie. Whether or not the semantics are useful, the fact that a method can be declared `private` and then accessed outside the class anyway is a bad design.

Comment: Note that `B b; b.someMethod();` is ill-formed but `B b; b.A::someMethod();` is well-formed.

Comment: @user2357112 The same would be true if we pass pointers to this function to the outside. `private` here is only a "lie" if you define "private" as *can only be called from the inside* (which still doesn't include the pointer-to-member-function). I'd say the access specifier only applies to the *name* of the function, not the function itself (as with linkage). The *name* `B::someMethod` is not accessible from outside.

Comment: This code works, but I didn't check it with compiler, I mean - the idea works, maybe there are some missing semicolons or somethink.

Comment: The Standard is pretty clear about the fact that access specifiers apply to names (not code). It would be seriously broken, and stupid, if you could make existing function calls fail at runtime just by privately overriding them in a subclass.

Comment: @user2357112 Do you have an idea for a clever and working design which would still be useable?

Comment: @Zaibis Why would it be not allowed? `A` is a public base class of `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following code, a modification of the code in the original question:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void X(){
        std::cout << "A::someMethod";
    }
};
class B : public A
{
private:
    virtual void Y(){
        std::cout << "B::someMethod";
    }
};
int main(){
    A* a = new B;
    a->X();
}
```

It's easy to understand that it's legit to call X(). B inherits it from A as a public member. Theoretically if X() would call Y() this would be legit as well of course, although this is not possible because X() is declared in A which doesn't know Y(). But actually this is the case if X = Y, i.e. if both methods have the same name.

You may think of it as "B inherits a public method from A, that calls a private method (of B) with the same name".

Comment: @friko Then you should accept it (by clicking the green tick-mark next to it). That's how SO works.

Answer (score 1):

For me this is quite simple.
As you are allowed to asign any dynamic type inheritance of a class to an object of the parrent-class it would be vise versa.But as you are assigning the Child to its parrent object pointer this could be bad as if the class of B where bigger as A.

> If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through an lvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
> - the dynamic type of the object,
> - a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to the dynamic type of the object,
> - a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a cv-qualified version of the dynamic type of the object,
> - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union),
> - a type that is a (possibly cv-qualified) base class type of the dynamic type of the object,
> - a char or unsigned char type.

So as in your code you aren't fitting this conditions, but as B has the sime size as A, it would be possible to run it. But it is undefined behavior.
And as you creat a `new B` the memory block a is pointing to has the method of printing B and not A.

Answer (score 1):

`a` is a pointer to an `A` object where the method is public, so this is not a violation. Since, you have used `virtual`, the VTABLE is taken into account and you get the output as B::someMethod.

Comment: I dont't care if the vtable is taken into account or that the base method in A is public. What is realy important to me is that the private method can be called from the world. If I declare a method to be private I want to be sure, that no one can call my method unless I use friend. I think that my above example violates OOP rules...

Comment: @friko If it was impossible to call `B::someMethod`, that would violate the LSP.

Comment: @friko Don't override a virtual function then. It's your choice.

Comment: @AlanStokes Actually, it's more like "don't override a *public* virtual function *privately.*" Which I certainly think is a weird thing to do.

Comment: @Zaibis `A` is an accessible base class of `B`. There's **no** UB involved.

Answer (score 1):

The access control specifiers (`public`, `protected` and `private`) do not apply to member functions or data members. They apply to member function and data member *names.* And that works. If you can refer to the member without the name, you can access it.

That's precisely what's happening here. You're calling `B::someMethod`, but you're calling it using the name `A::someMethod`, which is public. No problem.

You're suggesting a private member function shouldn't be callable from outside of the class (disregarding friends for the moment). How would your desired semantics work in the following case?

**Shared library `hider`:**

`hider.h`:

```
typedef void (*FuncType)();

class Hider {
private:
  static void privFunc();

public:
  static void pubFunc();

  FuncType getFunction() const;
};
```

`hider.cpp`

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include "hider.h"

void Hider::privFunc() {
  std::cout << "Private\n";
}

void Hider::pubFunc() {
  std::cout << "Public\n";
}

FuncType Hider::getFunction() const {
  if (std::rand() % 2) {
    return &pubFunc;
  } else {
    return &privFunc;
  }
}
```

**Application using library `hider`**

```
#include "hider.hpp"

int main()
{
  Hider h;
  FuncType f = h.getFunc();
  f();
}
```

What about the call to `f()`? Should it fail at runtime 50% of the time with some form of `access control violation`?

---

As suggested by DyP in the comments, a more realistic scenario is the well-known "template method" design pattern:

```
class Container
{
public:
  void insert(const Item &item) {
    preInsert();
    data.insert(item);
    postInsert();
  }

private:
  std::vector<Item> data;

  virtual void preInsert() = 0;
  virtual void postInsert() = 0;
};


class ThreadSafeContainer : public Container
{
private:
  std::mutex m;

  virtual void preInsert() {
    m.lock();
  }

  virtual void postInsert() {
    m.unlock();
  }
};
```

Your semantics would mean this code wouldn't compile.

Comment: That is a weird example o.O maybe (also) show the template pattern as an example for `private` virtuals (as suggested by the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/private-virtuals.html))?

Comment: @DyP Sure, the example's somewhat crazy (although generally, using a `private static` as a callback is a legitimate scenario). But I just wanted to highlight the distinction between "control access to member" and "control access to name." The template method is a good suggestion, I will add it. Thanks.